# React redux best practice for table row action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list of items.
I render a Table component with this list.
I want to add a checkbox for each row.
Do I have to use a separate component for the table row iteself in order to set the current row style by checking it without rendering the whole table?
Becasase now when I change the item's 'selected' property, the whole table is rendering.

Thanks :)

Comment: React has smart rerendering so I would not worry about performance. There is no right way of how to divide your components. For me It's sound natural for row to be a separate component.

Comment: Actually I ask this question because I have performance issues. I render the table with a list of item, then by selecting each row I dispatch an action that changes the item's selection property. But when displaying more than 200 rows it becomes very slow, and my thoughts it's because I didn't use a separate component for the row itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your whole table re-render, you should clearly update your code to avoid that. Like you said, you can have a component for each row, so when a row update, only the row re-render. I'm strongly suggesting you to do this. Be sure to include a key prop to each row to avoid performance leak. You can also use the `shouldComponentUpdate` method to avoid useless re-render. When passing your props down from the table component to the row component, make sure the objects your are passing are unique on don't change too often. If after all this, you realised you row will update and re-render often, you can try using [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized), this library renders only the rows that are visible on the screen. If you need more help, you can also share some code.

Comment: Now it's clearer :) My second question is how to perform the selection operation - do I need to save tge selected state as a property for each item, or to save a list of selected items?

Comment: If you want to easily get access to the selected rows, I will suggest you to not keep the value in each item, either store it in the redux state if you think you will need them elsewhere in the app, or in the table component state. You will be able to pass is the row is selected or now as a prop to the row component.